# What is the syntax for specifying a environment in save in R?

Tags: r, rlang

I am trying to save everything in a named environment to an RDS file.

This was my attempt:

```
myenv <- new_environment(data = list(), parent = empty_env())
...put some variables in myenv
save(list = ls(all.names = TRUE), file = "fileName", envir = myenv)
```

But it says "invalid 'envir' argument" and I can't find any examples that don't use the global environment or parent.frame().

What is the syntax of the "envir =" parameter?

Comment: You have to call the `ls` function with additional argument `envir = myenv`

Comment: Thanks @Jonas - you mean save(list = ls(all.names = TRUE, envir = myenv), file = "fileName", envir = myenv). I would never have guessed that.